# How is the identitiy of a subject in a Public Key Certificate verified by the Certificate Authority (CA)?

Tags: ssl, certificate, x509certificate, public-key-encryption

A general digital certificate issued by a CA might contain information about the individual/organization to whom the certificate belongs. As an example, consider this sample scenario:

[image: Sample PKC]

This PKC contains identifying information of the individual to whom is this certificate is issued, i.e. the Name (Mario Rossi), Organization (Wikimedia), and so on. For a more concrete example, here is an excerpt of the PKC data issued to Wikimedia, containing info about their company name, address and domain:

```
...
Subject: C=US, ST=California, L=San Francisco, O=Wikimedia Foundation, Inc., CN=*.wikipedia.orgSubject 
...
```

My question is what are the standards used by the CA to ensure that these claimed details about the Subject's name, address, domain, etc are genuine and not being falsely claimed by forger? Additionally, what kind of subject-related-data, in addition to names, addresses, etc., can be expected to be verfied by the CA?

Answer (score 1):

The task of verifying the subject is delegated to the Registration Authority (RA) role.

The exact process for verification depends on the PKI use-case, but can vary from simple automated checking of DNS records (ACME protocol) to presenting national IDs, driving licences or passports to the RA in person.

The identity, authorisation and verification requirement for a particular PKI will be defined in it's [Certificate Policy (CP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_policy) - section 3 if it's [RFC 3647](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3647) compliant.  The CA must then design and implement its technology and processes in-line with this CP and document its compliance within its [Certification Practice Statement (CPS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certification_Practice_Statement).

RFC 3647 only defines the headings and sub-headings of the CP (and CPS) but it does not define the minimum standard.  That is left to the CP author using external guidance from industry specific standards if they exist, otherwise they must carry out a risk analysis and define their own internal standard.

For example, a PKI which issues certificates whose trust-anchors are part of the major browser vendor's Root CA programmes will need to ensure they follow the requirement of the [CA/Browser Forum's Baseline Requirements](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/).  Current versions of that document also follow the RFC 3647 layout, so you can find information on verification in section 3 of that document too.

These additional requirements guide the definition of the CP and are designed to ensure any PKI which asserts compliance provides the expected level of assurance. Many schemes will audit the PKI for compliance before it is permitted to operate.

If you're defining your own, you will need to balance the additional cost (both financial and time) of a strict RA regime vs convenience.